# htaccess allow just a specific url for a specific subdomain and disallow all the rest

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, content-indexing

We have 2 subdomains for our websites.

> - subdomain1.xxxxx.com
> - subdomain2.xxxxx.com

(We just create the second one a couple of days ago)

What I'm trying to accomplish with the .htaccess:

All the `subdomain2.xxxxx.com/???` urls must NOT be visible by the search engines.
Infact we find out that Google started to index all the urls with both subdomains and we don't want that.

We will like to use the second subdomain just for a specific url, for example:

> subdomain2.xxxxx.com/live/

All the other urls MUST not working with the second subdomain.
So Google must index just this url with the second subdomain:

> subdomain2.xxxxx.com/live/

Nothing else...
While al the other urls (for example: `subdomain1.xxxxx.com/video/` or `subdomain1.xxxxx.com/photo/` and all the others) must still visible and indexed within the subdomain1.
Off course `subdomain1.xxxxx.com/live/` MUST NOT working because will work just with the subdomain2.

How can I do that with the .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file in document root called `subdomain2-robots.txt`: with this content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
Allow: /live/
```

Then add this rule in .htaccess right under document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain2\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ /subdomain2-robots.txt [L,NC]
```